What is the best way to query and filter data from an AWS DynamoDB table?
Let us say that we have an AWS DynamoDB table called Table. Below is the JSON representation of the data we store in Table.
{
  "attr1": <attribute 1>,
  "attr2": <attribute 2>,
  "attr3": {
    "sub_attr1": <sub-attribute 1>,
    "sub_attr2": <sub-attribute 2>,
    "sub_attr3": <sub-attribute 3>,
  },
}

Now I want to be able to use these sub-attributes as filters. In other words, I want to be able to select 1 or more of the values of these sub-attributes, and retrieve all samples/documents from this table that hold these value/s for their respective sub-attribute/s.
For example, let us say that we wanted to filter based on the value of sub_attr2 being value2. In Python, one way to do this is the following:
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr

data = table.scan(
  FilterExpression=Attr('attr3.sub_attr2').eq('value2')
)

However, the problem with this approach is that using scan can be expensive in terms of read capacity consumption because it reads every item in the entire table and then discards unwanted data.
A better alternative to scan is query, however, the query operation in DynamoDB is designed to work with primary key attribute values and cannot be used to directly filter on nested attributes. To be able to use query, we would first need to flatten the data by promoting all of these nested sub-attributes to top-level attributes, and create secondary indexes on each promoted attribute.
My question is, are there other ways we can go about this? In other words, are there any ways in which we can keep the top-level attributes and the sub-attributes separate, and still be able to filter the contents of Table in a quick, efficient, and cost-effective manner?
Thanks in advance for all your responses.

No, this is the tradeoff. You need to design the table structure and secondary indexes to match the kind of queries you intend to preform.

Thanks for the reply! So in this case, would you say that flattening the data and creating secondary indexes for each sub-attribute that is promoted to a top-level attribute is the only/best approach? Or is there perhaps another approach?

What Mark mentioned in the comments is right. You can't use either a GSI or an LSI on a nested property of your pre-existing data. You will have to transform your records such that the property you'd like to query against is a top-level property of each DynamoDB row.
On a side note, you also need to consider that:

LSI can't be installed after the creation of a table
GSI is a much more appropriate key for this situation because it could be added after the DynamoDB table's creation
Installing a GSI to a pre-existing table will result to backfilling of the GSI and the speed on which this will occur will depend on the number of rows inside your table (1 row = 1 second). Queries against the table during this backfilling activity will not go through.
A less disruptive approach to get around item 3 if you have lots of data is to make a version 2 of your table with a new GSI, copy the data to your new  table to avoid downtime against the original table. Once this is complete, you can now reroute transactions from the original table to the new table.

